# Rails 3 Devise confirmation filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm wondering if it's possible to selectively require confirmation for certain controller actions using Devise.

Basically: I want users to sign up for an account (which will trigger a confirmation email), be automatically logged in, and **be able to immediately explore certain parts of the site as a signed in (but still unconfirmed)** user. Access to **certain areas (e.g., payment) would require the user to first confirm their email**.

I'm hoping for something like `before_filter: user_is_confirmed, only: [payment_related_stuff]`

I searched for a while and could not find a way to do this out of the box, so I thought creating a hacky solution in which all possibly protected areas would still require `before_filter: authenticate!`, but I would override the Devise SessionsController's create to permissibly allow access to certain areas before confirmation. However, I'm not sure if this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using built in solution in devise, you could use `allow_unconfirmed_access_for 1.year` in combination with `current_user.confirmed?` in your before filter

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I want. This [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/plataformatec-devise/OOBqd4qMpuc/AYJWuYZHT58J) explains it in more detail.