# Devise, skip confirmation until user tries to do something meaningful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, devise-confirmable

I want to let new users signup and browse my site without having to confirm their email addresses, until they try to do anything meaningful like create a new project, upload a video or leave a comment.

Does Devise have any hooks for doing this sort of thing?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do it like you want but if you ever want to create a guest user maybe this article can help you: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to do it in combination of postponing email confirmation via `allow_unconfirmed_access_for` and `confirmed?` for specific actions, like described in similar [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619388/rails-3-devise-confirmation-filter) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083887/why-wont-devise-allow-unconfirmed-users-to-login-even-when-allow-unconfirmed-ac).

BTW, starting from Devise 2.2.4 `allow_unconfirmed_access_for` accepts `nil` for unlimited access without confirmation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. The links were helpful.